# Usb drive died after zeroing out with dd, appears as Generic_USB_Flash_Disk-0:0 with size appearing undefined (-)

Tags: linux, usb-flash-drive

I have USB drive and I wanted to install Arch GNU/Linux on a old laptop so I decided to flash Arch GNU/Linux Iso but I noticed that when I booted into arch installer, it shown garbled data in the boot screen so I **zeroed out the disk with `# dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdb bs=1024` (then I would flash arch again). After zeroing is complete drive became unusable**, attempting to create a new partition table results in odd behavior **and data does not survive after ejecting the flash drive.**

Another odd thing is when I type `# eject -t /dev/sdb` drive starts to get reported as 2TB with any write to it failing with **Input/Output error**, usb drive I have is legit and does not have size tampered with it in first place, I originally bought it as 8gb drive and It was 8GB until now.

**After running some commands that I forgot about somehow I managed to create a partition table and create a partition but maximum size I could do was 837MB** which is same as Arch Iso I have which is another odd thing, no matter what I couldn't bring back drive to it's old size (8GB) and retent data after reset.

So question is, is this drive a toast? Can It be repaired, i'm worried about somehow I managed to corrupt drive's internal firmware which would explain odd reportings in size.

Comment: maybe try one of the many `usb thumb drive repair tools` spruiking their wares out there - personally, when a $5 thumb drive starts misbehaving, I toss it

Comment: Nope, the drive is toast. The "zeroing" was the last straw, it was showing symptoms before. BTW, doing that is ridiculously overkill (not that mattered much in this case), when an ISO "burn" results incorrect just do it again and/or try another stick.

Comment: Flash memory has a finite number of write cycles. Zeroing out every bit effectively used up all it's life.

Comment: What a vague story.. "After running some commands that I forgot about somehow I managed to create a partition table and create a partition but maximum size I could do was 837MB".. Where do you see this? How about some screenshots?